# Heat Transfer from variable profile truncated fin in Maple

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, modeling

I have a truncated, triangular fin with a rectangular base (width/thickness "w").

The profile is variable, described by: y=-((y0-yL)/L)*x)+y0

The tip is insulated, wall is a constant temperature (Tb).

I am trying to create an expression for temperature (assuming steady state, 1D conduction). I'm making a mistake somewhere when using the wall (base of the fin) as x=0, tip at x=L, in that I cannot get a solution/the correct solution.

However, when I reverse the coordinate system such that the the wall is x=L, and the fin tip is x=0 - I can generate the correct solution!

I know its the correct solution as I've modeled the fin in COMSOL as well, and can match the result.

I've been staring at this for a few days now and can't find the mistake in the MAPLE code (or error in math), would appreciate any fresh eyes that can move me towards fixing it such that either method produces a solution.

**Working version**
restart:

```
fin_profile:=-((y0-yL)/L)*x+y0;

eq4:=diff(T(x),x,x)+(dAc_x*(1/Ac))*diff(T(x),x)-h/k/Ac*dAs_x*(T(x)-Tinf)=0;

y:=m*x+b;Ac:=2*y*w;P:=4*y+2*w;dAc_x:=diff(Ac,x);

dAs_x:=P*sqrt(1+diff(y,x)^2);eq4;

eq7:=rhs(dsolve(eq4,T(x)));eq8:=diff(eq7,x):

b1:=subs(x=L,eq7)=Tb;

b2:=subs(x=0,-k*Ac*eq8)=0;

eq8:=solve({b1,b2},{_C1,_C2});assign(eq8)

Temp:=(eq7):

fin_profile;m:=(y0-yL)/L;b:=yL;

L:=0.4;k:=177;Tinf:=25;h:=10;w:=10/100;Tb:=100;y0:=2/100;yL:=1/100;Temp:

plot(Temp,x=0..L);

eq9:=Re(evalf(subs(x=0,-k*Ac*diff(Temp,x))));eq10:=Re(evalf(subs(x=L,Temp)));eq11:=Re(evalf(subs(x=0,Temp)));
```

**broken version**

```
restart:
fin_profile:=-((y0-yL)/L)*x+y0;

eq4:=diff(T(x),x,x)+(dAc_x*(1/Ac))*diff(T(x),x)-h/k/Ac*dAs_x*(T(x)-Tinf)=0;

y:=m*x+b;Ac:=2*y*w;P:=4*y+2*w;dAc_x:=diff(Ac,x);

dAs_x:=P*sqrt(1+diff(y,x)^2);eq4;

eq7:=rhs(dsolve(eq4,T(x)));eq8:=diff(eq7,x):

b1:=subs(x=0,eq7)=Tb;

b2:=subs(x=L,-k*Ac*eq8)=0;

eq8:=solve({b1,b2},{_C1,_C2});assign(eq8)

Temp:=(eq7):

fin_profile;m:=-(y0-yL)/L;b:=y0;

L:=0.4;k:=177;Tinf:=25;h:=10;w:=10/100;Tb:=100;y0:=2/100;yL:=1/100;Temp:

plot(Temp,x=0..L);

eq9:=Re(evalf(subs(x=L,k*Ac*diff(Temp,x))));eq10:=Re(evalf(subs(x=L,Temp)));eq11:=Re(evalf(subs(x=0,Temp)));
```

...

Comment: What is the meaning of variables $y_0$ and $y_L$? Seems like there could be a problem in the fin profile equation.

Comment: $y_0$ and $y_L$ are placeholder variables that describe the height of the fin from the center axis. $y_0$ is the fin height at the wall, $y_L$ is the fin height at the tip (i.e. $y(0) = y_0, y(L) = y_L$ )

The fin is mirrored about the x-axis, so total fin height is $2*y$.

This gives me a thought on approaching the problem via symmetry, will have to try that.

Comment: Could you provide figure with the coordinate system, fin dimensions and location of the wall? The problem is hard to understand just from the text/code.